# Scala read csv file and sort the file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have read a csv file to dataframe and I want to sort the df in asc order

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, DataFrame, SparkSession}
scala> df.sort($"year","state".ASC)
```

> :37: error: value sort is not a member of Unit
>          df.sort($"year","state".ASC)

what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.asc
df.sort(asc("column_name"))
```

Or, you could do it like this:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
df.sort($"column_name".asc)
```

Comment: thanks, I also found out that my df was actually empty, that was why the command didn't work